Cannot get tags from `org-clock-get-table-data`
I got an org file like this:
* TODO One                                                              :ONE:
:LOGBOOK:
CLOCK: [2024-11-17 Sun 19:06]--[2024-11-17 Sun 20:06] =>  1:00
:END:


* TODO Two                                                              :TWO:
:LOGBOOK:
CLOCK: [2024-11-17 Sun 18:06]--[2024-11-17 Sun 19:00] =>  0:54
:END:


#+begin_src elisp
(nth 1 (nth 2 (org-clock-get-table-data (current-buffer) '())))

; (1 #("Two" 0 3 (:org-clock-minutes 54 face org-level-1 fontified t)) nil nil 54 nil)
#+end_src

#+RESULTS:
| 1 | Two | nil | nil | 54 | nil |

When I run (nth 1 (nth 2 (org-clock-get-table-data (current-buffer) '()))) on the buffer with this content, I get info corresponding to the second heading like this:
(1 #("Two" 0 3 (:org-clock-minutes 54 face org-level-1 fontified t)) nil nil 54 nil)

As per the docstring of org-clock-get-table-data, the second nil should have been the tag.
The return value will be a list with the file name and the total
file time (in minutes) as 1st and 2nd elements.  The third element
of this list will be a list of headline entries.  Each entry has the
following structure:

  (LEVEL HEADLINE TAGS TIMESTAMP TIME PROPERTIES)

Why is it showing nil instead of the tag name "TWO"?
What am I missing here?

Org version: 9.3
Emacs version: 27.1


https://emacs.stackexchange.com/tags/elisp/info

You need to specify the option :tags in the params argument of org-clock-get-table-data. Try:
#+begin_src elisp :results drawer
  
 (org-clock-get-table-data (current-buffer) '(:tags t))

#+end_src

#+RESULTS:
:results:
(foo3.org 114 ((1 One (ONE) nil 60 nil) (1 Two (TWO) nil 54 nil)))
:end:

See the Clock Table section in the manual.

Oh.. Thanks. Adding the param did it.
